# Adding uniqueness to columns in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have the following case, table Article and table Fruit. Both are represented below

```
create table Article
(
    ART_ID          bigint not null auto_increment,
    ART_NAME         varchar(25) not null,
    primary key(ART_ID)
);

create table Fruit
(    
    ART_ID bigint not null,
    FRU_DES varchar(25) not null,
    Foreign Key (ART_ID) references Article(ART_ID)
);
```

Now it's OK as far as I am concerned, however when I want to input some data in order to create Fruit, I can't create that object in table without declaring ART_ID, however how is that possible if I have already declared it as auto_increment.

I can't do the following instruction to my DB,

```
insert into Fruit(FRU_DES)
values('dsd');
```

however I can do

```
insert into Fruit(ART_ID, FRU_DES)
values(1,'dsd');
```

But I don't want this scenario to have cause it may cause some problems if something is omitted in some time later stage of this project.

Comment: By the way. What's the primary key on teh fruit table...

Comment: Is it mandatory to have primary key in that table?

Comment: Depends on whether you want to allow an article to have two dsd fruits, and deal with issues like how to delete one of them when they can't be uniquely identified. Personally I'd avoid that, and always have a primary key on every table

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you put the foreign key on you said to be a valid fruit, there must be a reference to a valid article.

In an ORM or other code model `AddFruit` would be a method on Article, ie Art_ID is known before you make the attempt.

In straight sql, perhaps

```
Insert into Fruit Select Article.Art_ID,'apple' From Article Where Article.Artname = 'Still life by P Frame'
```

makes it clear.

Comment: OK, but what if I declared Article just as template( abstract table ) in order not to multiply my sub tables with the same columns?

Comment: Sub tables should be the default option. ie Do a normalised design, then denormalise if you really really really have to, and prepare to be made sorry in version 2. Perhaps @Laoujin answer would help morte than mine from waht you are saying.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you'll need a third table:

- Your Article table as is
- Your fruit table gets a `FRU_ID auto_increment` and the `ART_ID` column is discarded
- The ArticleFruit table which contains ART_ID and FRU_ID columns

This would allow you to insert Fruits once in your database without linking it directly to an Article while you can still link Fruits to Articles by adding records to the ArticleFruit table.

Comment: If I pass NULL, that would mean it's not referenced to an existing Article, ie it doesn't have it's number. I deem it's valid, however my cmd says it's not.

Comment: Oops, I misread the table definitions. I'll update my answer.